# Understanding code logic in alphabetical sorting

Tags: java, string, eclipse, if-statement

I have problem understanding how this code sorts the cities into alphabetical order. I don't understand the logic in the if loops and if someone explain to me how the "switching" works and why the first and last if block statements are the same?

I tried attempting this problem myself but my logic was flawed and I don't get how this logic works.

I know this could be done simpler with arrays and sorting that I have seen but I am a beginner in Java and still trying to learn if statements and strings.

Thank you.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Cars {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter first city");
        String first = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter second city");
        String second = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter third city");
        String third = sc.nextLine();


        String temp = "";
        if(first.compareTo(second)>0) {
            temp = second;
            second = first;
            first = temp;
        }
        if(second.compareTo(third) > 0) {
            temp = third;
            third = second;
            second = temp;
        }
        if(first.compareTo(second) > 0) {
            temp = second;
            second = first;
            first = temp;
        }
        System.out.println("alphabetical order" + " " + first + " " + second +" " + third);
    }
}
```

Comment: The comapare to method for strings return the ascii difference. please let me know if you looking for more details

Comment: I suggest you to modify the code to add a print in each statements, so you can understand what happen. Add 2 print inside each if, one before the swapping, and one after. And in your print display the three data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How the switching works ?**

```
temp = second; // Store the second element in a temporary variable
second = first; // Replace the second element by the first
first = temp; // Replace the first element by the temporary (the old second)
```

This part of code just swap two elements.

**Why is the third block the same as the first ?**

> Because swapping may have already occurred in the first two block

An example may talks better than theory, let's have input like that :

```
first = "b";
second = "c";
third = "a";
```

The first swapping block will compare `first` with `second`, they are already in good order, so no swapping is done :

```
first = "b";
second = "c";
third = "a";
```

The second block will compare `second` with `third`, they are in the wrong order, so we swap them, resulting in :

```
first = "b";
second = "a";
third = "c";
```

***Here is the point :*** we now need to compare what hasn't been compared the initial first with the initial third, so actual first with actual second (looks like the first block), resulting in :

```
first = "a";
second = "b";
third = "c";
```

But what if second and third had not been swapped ? In this case, we would know that second and first is correctly ordered (due to first block), and that second and third are correctly ordered too (due to second block), so we know that the whole data are sorted, and we don't care about the third block, it won't be entered.

Answer (score 1):

The first lines are supposed to read city names from the standard input:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter first city");
String first = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter second city");`
String second = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter third city");
String third = sc.nextLine();
```

Then you compare and swap positions. Read the javadoc of String.compareTo(String anotherString) method.

> @return  the value {@code 0} if the argument string is equal to this string; a value less than {@code 0} if this string is lexicographically less than the string argument; and a value greater than {@code 0} if this string is lexicographically greater than the string argument

So we compare the first name with the second. If the second city name is lexicographically greater than the first we use temp variable to swap the positions of the cities

```
String temp = "";
if(first.compareTo(second)>0) {
    temp = second;
    second = first;
    first = temp;
}
```

Now we know the partial order. We need to compare the second with the third and then again the first with the third to be sure all 3 city names are sorted lexicographically

```
if(second.compareTo(third) > 0) {
    temp = third;
    third = second;
    second = temp;
}
if(first.compareTo(second) > 0) {
    temp = second;
    second = first;
    first = temp;
 }
```

Basically, it's the bubble sort for the list size = 3
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Answer (score 1):

I will explain what this code does:

```
if(first.compareTo(second)>0) {
    temp = second;
    second = first;
    first = temp;
}
if(second.compareTo(third) > 0) {
    temp = third;
    third = second;
    second = temp;
}
if(first.compareTo(second) > 0) {
    temp = second;
    second = first;
    first = temp;
}
```

Let's say `first` contains `C`, `second` contains `B` and `third` contains `A`.

At first, `first`, `second` and `third` are unsorted.

(first `if`) If the city in `first` should come after the city in `second`, swap them. How do we swap them? We first copy second to a temporary variable `temp`, put whatever is in `first` into `second`, then put whatever is in `temp` into `first`. It's easier to visualise if you think of the variables as boxes, and the values you are swapping as balls.

After the first if has been run, `first` contains `B`, `second` contains `C` and `third` contains `A`

(second `if`) If `second` should come after `third`, swap them. Now, `first` contains `B`, `second` contains `A` and `third` contains `C`.

Now you should notice that by running the first two if statements, we have found what should be in `third`. Now we just need to figure out whether `first` and `second` are sorted, which is done in the third if statement.

Why is the third if statement doing the same thing as the first if statement?

They have the same code, but the third if runs after the first and second if, by which time, `first` and `second` would have different values.

Answer (score 0):

That code is bubble sort for 3 element.

Usually it use loops, but in case you have only 3 elements (any constant number of elements) you can get rid of them.